# How to get SID of Windows domain using WMIC?

Tags: windows-domain, wmic

I’m looking for a WMIC solution to obtain a Windows domain's SID. I can only find solutions for PowerShell, however I prefer the WMIC approach.

Lots of examples exist on Google for obtaining domain users’ SID, but none tell how to obtain a computer or domain's SID.

Comment: wmic useraccount list ?

Comment: Just to clarify you're not looking for a AD user SID, but rather a AD computer (object) SID or the domain itself SID (unfamiliar with that)? If so wmic may be the wrong tool for the job since its focus is on the local machine, you'd have to look to powershell or adquery commands. Unless you are going to run wmic /node switch against an AD server?

Comment: @gregg - yes, I’m looking for SIDs associated with AD computers or the domain itself. What would the queries look like using adquery or wmic /node?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify. I'm honestly not sure if WMIC can provide the local PC SID (or remote PC via wmic os /node:"HOSTNAME"). adquery isn't a command, I meant dsquery; however it requires RSAT (Remote Server Admin Tools). So powershell seems to be the best built-in option, but it also may relay on RSAT. Here are some links:
https://ss64.com/nt/dsquery.html
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2693643/remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-operating-systems

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there isn't a "Domain SID" *per se*. I assume what you're referring to is the Domain Identifier which uniquely identifies a domain within the AD forest.

Each SID in an Active Directory domain includes the Domain Identifier. I'm not aware of a WMIC command that returns *only* this identifier; however, it's easy to extrapolate it by inspecting any principle's SID in the domain.

For example, the following WMIC command returns the SID of the Domain Admins group:

```
C:\>wmic group where name="Domain Admins" get name,sid,domain
Domain   Name           SID
CONTOSO  Domain Admins  S-1-5-21-1004336348-1177238915-682003330-512
```

As explained in the Microsoft Docs article [How Security Identifiers Work](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc778824(v%3Dws.10)), a SID is composed of the following components:

- A revision level (1)
- An identifier authority (5, NT Authority)
- **A domain identifier** (21-1004336348-1177238915-682003330, Contoso)
- A relative identifier (512, Domain Admins)

Therefore you simply need to strip off the revision level, identifier authority, and RID to derive the Domain Identifier portion.

Comment: What do you mean “per se”? Each domain has a SID itself, just like computers have SID issued by the domain.

Comment: What is “Contoso”? And you say “Domain Admins”, but write “Domain Users” underneath (512 vs. 513) - thanks!

Comment: Domain Users was a typo...I fixed that. [Contoso](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contoso?wprov=sfla1) is a fictional domain used as an example in Microsoft documentation. Can you link to information confirming there's such a thing as a domain SID?

Comment: See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246018.aspx: Especially the sentence: "Whenever a new issuing authority under Windows is created (for example, a new machine deployed or a domain created), it is assigned a SID"... Can you clarify?